# Swift Preview problem with @EnvironmentObject

Tags: swift, preview, environmentobject

I am having trouble getting an updated preview when using `@EnvironmentObject` in my Swift project. In the simulator it works fine, but previewing is not. The error it shows is following:

```
ASET - Audio System Engineer Tools crashed due to missing environment of type: UserSettings. To resolve this add `.environmentObject(UserSettings(...))` to the appropriate preview.
```

However, when I try to add it, it keeps on coming with the same issue. Anyone have some helpful advise or solution?

Answer (score 19):

Found the answer which was already posted on stack overflow: instead of just putting it in the preview struct, I had to declare it like this, which makes the preview update without any issues:

```
struct CalculatorView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(UserSettings())
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for me.
As soon as I move the @EnvironmentObject class to another library it starts crashing

Answer (score 5):

For those still having issues with the Preview but may not be related to this, you also have to inject it manually into the preview itself since it acts standalone and can't see your injection at the top level.

```
#Preview {
ContentView()
    .environmentObject(UserAuth())
}
```

Comment: You may also need to make sure that the UserAuth is wrapped with `@Observable` if you get an error like "Instance method 'environment' requires that 'UserAuth' conform to 'Observable'"